# CXF webservice client ignores ssl configuration http-conf:tlsClientParameters

Tags: java, spring, web-services, ssl, cxf

I'm trying to establish a SSL connection between a cxf client and a webservice.
For a proof-of-concept I'm running a test with the SpringJunit4TestRunner.
In my spring config for the client I'm using the following:

```
    <jaxws:client id="wsClient"  address="${webservice.endpoint.url}" serviceClass="MyServiceClass"/>
<http-conf:conduit name="${webservice.endpoint.url}">
        <http-conf:client ConnectionTimeout="${webservice.connectionTimeout}" />

        <http-conf:tlsClientParameters>            

            <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="changeit">
                <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="changeit" file="c:\temp\keystore\myKeyStore.jks" />
            </sec:keyManagers>
            <sec:trustManagers >
                <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="changeit" file="c:\temp\keystore\myKeyStore.jks"/>
            </sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
                <!-- these filters ensure that a ciphersuite with
                export-suitable or null encryption is used,
                but exclude anonymous Diffie-Hellman key change as
                this is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks -->
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
            </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>    
        </http-conf:tlsClientParameters>
    </http-conf:conduit>
```

However cxf does not seem to pick up my configuration. In the logs during startup I see a

```
10:38:58.581 [ProofOfConceptTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The location of the key store has not been set via a system parameter or through configuration so the default value of MYHOMEFOLDER.keystore will be used.
10:38:58.581 [ProofOfConceptTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The key store password has not been set via a system property or through configuration, reading data from the keystore will fail.
10:38:58.581 [ProofOfConceptTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The key password has not been set via a system property or through configuration, reading data from the keystore will fail.
10:38:59.252 [ProofOfConceptTaskExecutor-1] WARN  o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - Default key managers cannot be initialized: Password must not be null
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password must not be null
```

and after this the SSL connection fail with a sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

However, the keystore and its certificate chain seem to be correct as if I execute the test from the command line, passing the arguemnts for the keystore and truststore:

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=MyTestClass -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\temp\keystore\myKeyStore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\temp\keystore\myKeyStore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
```

everything works fine and the SSL connection work. So my conclusion is that CXF is ignoring the tlsClientParameters. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: if I remove my own TaskExecutor the issue remains, but in the logs I see

```
DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory The location of the key store has not been set via a system parameter or through configuration so the default value will be used
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use port name with qualified namespace for  http-conf:conduit name attribute. Check [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/schemas-and-namespaces.html) documentation.

Comment: nice, this works. Thank you! However I wonder why the connection timeout was being picked up correctly with my apparently wrong configuration?!

Comment: May I know what was fixed. I have a similar setup but production work, with same trust store on weblogic, it fails on my test env .